# How to connect a html page and web(chrome) by selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, web-crawler

I'm using selenium to crawling information from chrome web site.

I want to click the button on web by clicking a button on my html page.

```
<input type="button" class="bt1" id="bt1" name="record" value="record">
```

I made a button with this line. And I have an url where I want to crawl by selenium.

```
btnXpath = "//*[@id='root']/div/div[5]/button[4]"
```

This is a button path where I want to click.

```
if check_exists_by_xpath(btnXpath):

  driver1.execute_script("document.querySelector('#keywords').value = '';")

  driver1.find_element_by_xpath(btnXpath).click()

  eoj = False
```

I can click the button(btnXpath) but it is clicked at the same time when driver1 is executed.

But I want to activate the button when I click the button on my html page (bt1)

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: ad Jquery or JS to code that will execute crawler after button click

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?